# Group Permission for Azure DevOps via CLI

Tags: permissions, azure-devops, command-line-interface

I would like to remove the DELETE (Delete Project) permission from the Project Administrator role for each project in Azure DevOps. Here are the CLI commands that I am running. Everything goes without errors. However, when you go back and check on the web, the permissions are untouched. Any ideas?

```
$org = "myOrg"
$orgUrl = "https://dev.azure.com/$org"

$projName = "myProject"
$group = "Project Administrators"

$projId = az devops project list --org "$orgURl" -o json --query "value[?@.name == '$projName'].id | [0]"
$projToken = '$PROJECT:vstfs///Classification/TeamProject/'+$projId
$projToken = $projToken -Replace '"', ""

$subject = az devops security group list --org "$orgUrl" --scope organization -o json --subject-types vssgp --query "graphGroups[?@.principalName == '[$projName]\$group'].descriptor | [0]"

$namespaceId = az devops security permission namespace list -o json --org "$orgUrl" --query "[?@.name == 'Project'].namespaceId | [0]"

$bit = az devops security permission namespace show -o json --namespace-id $namespaceId --org "$orgUrl" --query "[0].actions[?@.name == 'DELETE'].bit | [0]" 

az devops security permission update --id $namespaceId --subject $subject --token $projToken --deny-bit $bit --org "$orgUrl" --merge true
```

Output is:
[PS Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CBoKU.png)

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance,
Jake

Comment: Project Administrator is almost the highest permission in project scope, the permissions about that group is not supported to edit...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Project Administrator Group owns the **highest** permissions in Team Project level. So the project permissions (Project Settings=>Permissions) about that group is not editable:

[image]

It's by design that Project Administrators will always have the permission to delete team project.

Except the `Project Administrators` group, other groups's permissions are editable, see:

[image]

1.So it you want to add one member to `Project Administrator` group, he's permission about deleting project can't be removed.

(No matter which way we use, Web page, Azure Devops Rest Api, az devops cli command or what, none of these would work since it's by design)

2.And if you do want to give one member most permissions the Project Administrator should have but except Delete Team Project permission, you can try creating a new group (In project Settings=>Permissions page) and give the group all permissions except Delete Team project permission, something like that:

[image]

You also need to do extra job to give the group necessary permissions in Pipeline Security(see pic below), Repos permissions(Project settings=>repos=>repos) ...

[image]

Then add the member into this Custom Group instead of default `Project Administrators` Group.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. I guess changing the default permission profile for Project Administrators will not work in that case. So I created a new group within the project with no explicit permission mapping. Then repeated the step to add the deny-bit (also tried allow-bit separately), but the permissions dont update within DevOps. Ideas?

Comment: The issue could be related to your `--token` parameter! Please check this [similar issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-devops-cli-extension/issues/912#issuecomment-561983505). It's recommended to use `single quotes` directly in last command instead of using variable like `$projToken`.

Comment: Use format like `az devops security permission update --id $namespaceId --subject $subject --token '$PROJECT:vstfs:///Classification/TeamProject/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx' --deny-bit 4 --merge true`. And it will work like a charm.

Comment: Thanks Lance! I think I finally have it working. Appreciate your help with this!!